# How to Concat 2 column of ArrayType on axis = 1 in Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, concatenation

I have a the following dataframe:

I would like to concatenate the **lat** and **lon** into a list. Where **mmsi** is similar to an ID (This is unique)

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     mmsi|                 lat|                 lon|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|255801480|[47.1018366666666...|[-5.3017783333333...|
|304182000|[44.6343033333333...|[-63.564803333333...|
|304682000|[41.1936, 41.1715...|[-8.7716, -8.7514...|
|305930000|[49.5221333333333...|[-3.6310166666666...|
|306216000|[42.8185133333333...|[-29.853155, -29....|
|477514400|[47.17205, 47.165...|[-58.6317, -58.60...|
```

Therefore, I would like to concatenate the lat and lon array but on axis = 1, that is, I would like to have at the end a list of lists, in a separate column, like:

```
[[47.1018366666666, -5.3017783333333], ... ]
```

How is that could be possible in pyspark dataframe? I have tried concat, but that will return:

```
[47.1018366666666, 44.6343033333333, ..., -5.3017783333333, -63.564803333333, ...]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting Spark version 2.4, you can use the inbuilt function **[`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip)**.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip
df.withColumn('zipped_lat_lon',arrays_zip(df.lat,df.lon)).show()
```

Comment: Thank you @Vamsi for your answer. I just figured out that I am getting back: `[{"lat":"47.101836666666664","lon":"-5.301778333333333"},{....` how can I remove the "lat" and "lon"?

Comment: the return type of the function is a named `struct`. if you post what actually resulted in that output, i can take a look